# Double integral of $e^{x^2+y^2}dydx$?

Tags: definite-integrals

I'd like to know the detailed solution of
$$\int_{x=0}^{x=1} \int_{y=0}^{y=2} e^{x^2+y^2} dy dx.$$

I know I must find $\int_{y=0}^{y=2} e^{x^2+y^2}dy$, first but I don't even know how to start it.

Comment: Do you know about polar coordinates? Do you know about the Normal distribution? In what context are you asking this question, for which class is this the homework for?

Answer (score 3):

Without context it's hard to suggest the tools, but for the exact problem you are posing notice that
$$
\int_{y=0}^{y=2} e^{x^2+y^2} dy
 = \int_{y=0}^{y=2} e^{x^2} e^{y^2} dy
 = e^{x^2} \int_{y=0}^{y=2} e^{y^2} dy
$$
So if we define $\int_0^x e^{u^2} du = F(x)$ then your double integral becomes
$$
\int_{x=0}^{x=1} \int_{y=0}^{y=2} e^{x^2+y^2} dy dx
 = \left( \int_{x=0}^{x=1} e^{x^2} dx \right) \cdot
   \left( \int_{y=0}^{y=2} e^{y^2} dy \right)
 = F(2) \cdot F(1).
$$
How you find $F(x)$ is a more complex problem.

Here is another approach. Note that you can switch to polar coordinates, and then
$$
\int \int e^{x^2+y^2} dxdy = \int \int e^{r^2} r dr d\theta
$$
and
$$
\int r e^{r^2} dr
$$
can be integrated using the substituion $u = r^2$. The trick is to map the region correctly, which for your square is not an easy thing to do either.

Hence me asking, in what context is your question?

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^1\int_0^2e^{x^2+y^2}~dy~dx$

$=\int_0^1\int_0^2e^{x^2}e^{y^2}~dy~dx$

$=\int_0^1e^{x^2}~dx\int_0^2e^{y^2}~dy$

$=\left[\dfrac{\sqrt\pi~\text{erfi}(x)}{2}\right]_0^1\left[\dfrac{\sqrt\pi~\text{erfi}(y)}{2}\right]_0^2$

$=\dfrac{\pi~\text{erfi}(1)~\text{erfi}(2)}{4}$